# looping over the structures within arrays

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to loop over the following array of structures, with the `name` and `value` column from the database. I cannot find a suitable way of doing it.

[image: dump of array of structures]

I tried the following:

```
<cfset kkn = getSettings() - This returns the results like array using querytoArray Function 
<cfloop array="#kkn#" index="k">
    <cfset email_Templates[k['name']] = k['HTML_Body']>
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>
<textarea name="tce" rows="10" class="textareas" cols="50">#email_Templates['log']#</textarea>

</cfoutput>
```

But it gives me this error:

```
email_Templates is undefined
```

Comment: where did you define `email_Templates` ?

Comment: Image link appears to be SPAM and contains no valid content.

Comment: I don't have an ad blocker. Using straight out Chrome.

Comment: Link is valid, just a crappy ad-laden site. There's not enough information present to answer the question though. What is the variable email_templates and where is it defined?

Comment: if i define email_templates using a cfparam, it gives me java error saying, i had try to dererence a scalar variable with string

Comment: That error means exactly what it says. You have declared the `email_templates` variable as a string but are trying to use it as if it is an array or a structure.  The original error was also pretty clear. You are trying to use a variable that does not exist. However, you did not answer Brad's question above:  *What is the variable `email_templates` and where is it defined?*

Comment: That is where i am confused, i do't want to use the `email_Templates`, all i want is to use the `name` and `html_body`, so i can populate my textarea like if i can specify with `name` as: `#templates['abc']#` - it should basically put the `html_body` contents inside that textarea

Comment: *i do't want to use the email_Templates* Well it is in your code, so it is involved .. somehow, but since you did not post sample values, we can only guess how the elements are related. (Though perhaps you meant **mail**_templates?)  There is not enough information to offer anything but guesses.  You need to update your question with samples of the structure values. Using the samples, explain what you want to retrieve and the expected result.  Feel free to sanitize, just preserve the context. ie Do not replace everything with "xxxx" so it is impossible to distinguish one item from another.

Answer (score 4):

There's not enough information in your question to answer the question with confidence, but have you tried using `Mail_Templates` instead of `email_templates`?